# Using \jot crashes \intertext’s spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, amsmath

As mentioned in [Intertext vertical spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/intertext-vertical-spacing), there seems to be some inconsistencies in spacing around AMS’ macro `\intertext`, even without changing the length of `\jot`. But if I’m using a longer `\jot` to get mor space between equations in array, the problem gets a real problem.

This is an example showing the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,ngerman,DIV=8]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\jot}{2\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
\begin{equation}
    m\cdot a\cdot t\cdot h = 0
\end{equation}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
\begin{align}
    m &= 0\\
\intertext{Intertext Intertext Intertext Intertext Intertext}
    a &= t\cdot h/2
\end{align}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
\begin{align}
    (a+b)^2 &\neq \left(a^2+b^2\right)\cdot\left(a^2+b^2\right)\\
    &=\left(a^2+2ab+b^2\right)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how to get exactly the same spacing with `\intertext` as without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m sorry … a few minutes after asking I’ve fount the solution via Google:
[Here](http://conway.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/wiki/blog/posts/Beyond_amsmath/) one can find a package called `amsmath1` which fixes the spacing problem :-)

Shall I send a bug report to AMS?

Comment: no, report it to the maintainer of `mathtools` so it can be fixed there. `amsmath` is frozen, and fixing the bug there would break a lot of existing documents.

Comment: @Phillipp: But then I have to load `mathtools`additionally, right? Does it work together with the AMS packages?

Comment: … by now i noticed that `mathtools` loads `amsmath` so I can replace it :-)

Comment: … and I sent an e-mail to the maintainers of `mathtools` (Why can’t I edit my last comments?)

Comment: Update: The developers of `mathtools` fixed it an it shall be available in the next release this summer. (@Philipp)