# Is it possible to break up an align environment and keep the tab positions?

Tags: align, notes

I'd like to take notes for a math class such that I can typeset a series of equations with the `\align` environment and make some text notes in between some of the lines. As far as I can tell, though... by using `\end{align*}`, typing some text notes about the process, and then starting a new `\begin{align*}`, I won't be able to align the = symbols in the above environment with & anymore.

The best I could come up with is to use `\text{}` in the middle of the equations, but that doesn't place the text along the left margin of the document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\begin{document}
  This is a series of equations:
  \begin{align*}
    x^{2}+y^{2}&=0\\
    y&=mx+b\\
    \text{This is a note about the above lines}\\
    &\text{This is another note}\\
    x^{2}&=1
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\intertext` and `\shortintertext`.

Comment: That's neat - didn't know about those. What is the difference between those two?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I break an align environment for a paragraph?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9577/how-can-i-break-an-align-environment-for-a-paragraph) See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/intertext-vertical-spacing

Answer (score 7):

`amsmath` provides `\intertext`, which interrupts your align, and lets you add some text. Sometimes, however, the spacing around the `\intertext` is too large, so the `mathtools` package provides `\shortintertext`. Compare:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{align}
a & = b \\
\intertext{Some note.}
c & = d \\
\shortintertext{Another note.}
e & = f
\end{align}
```