# Formatting equations and text in amsmath

Tags: formatting, amsmath

I'm working on a document on how to solve some basic integral problems. However, I'm having difficulty getting `\begin{equation}\end{equation}` to do what I need it to do. I would like all of my equations to be aligned (why I started looking at the equation environment) and numbered, but I would also like to put lines of text between parts of the equation to document what is happening.

My problem is, lines of text are inline with equations no matter what I type. Here's what I've tried.

```
\begin{equation}
\vec{F_{net}} = m \vec{a}\\
\text{This is a basic equation, and is also on the same line as the previous example}
\end{equation}
```

This code compiles fine, but everything is on one line and runs off the page. What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: You should just put the `\text` *outside* the `equation`. Why not?

Comment: @Werner - the OP's write-up wasn't very clear on this point, but he/she may have meant to write that the text is to be inserted between equations that are to be aligned (say, on some equal sign)...

Comment: @Mico: Then the OP should see [Is it possible to break up an `align` environment and keep the tab positions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100867/5764) and its associated duplicates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one equation and some running text between the equations, you should probably use either the `\intertext` macro of the `amsmath` package or the `\shortintertext` macro of the `mathtools` package. As the second macro name suggests, it's meant for cases of only a few words between successive equations.

Separately, to have several equations aligned vertically, you should look into using the `align` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\vec{F}_{\text{net}} &= m \vec{a} \label{eq:fnet}\\
\intertext{This is a basic equation, and is also on the same line as the previous example. And some more text. And still more text.} 
E &= mc^2 \label{eq:einstein}
\end{align}

Here are some cross-references to equations \eqref{eq:fnet} and \eqref{eq:einstein}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\vec{F}_\text{net} = m \vec{a}\\
\intertext{This is the Newton's second law of motion when the mass does not change with time. But for time-varying mass, we have to use}
\vec{F}_\text{net} = \frac{\textrm{d}(m\vec{v})}{\textrm{d}t}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP's write-up wasn't entirely clear, but he/she may be looking to place text *between* equations that are to be aligned vertically.