# How to expand \align mode into two pages by following the end line of the previous page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, page-breaking, align

I have a big matrix and each element of it has many stuff. The problem I'm facing is that the `align` mode is trying to make each equation to be fitted into one page. For example, in the following code I have a matrix in a separate align mode and its elements in another `align` equation as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
P = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
P_{11} & P_{12} & P_{13} & P_{14} \\
P_{21} & P_{22} & P_{23} & P_{24} \\
P_{31} & P_{32} & P_{33} & P_{34} \\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align*}

where 

\begin{align*}
P_{11} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{12} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{13} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{14} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
P_{21} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{22} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{23} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{24} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
P_{31} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{32} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{33} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{34} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

From the below picture, the elements of the matrix are taking more than one page in my actual case, so the elements have been placed in a separate page. The previous page is having only the actual matrix (i.e. P) , therefore the page almost empty. How can I force the equation mode to be in the line text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to adjust things manually. You need to be able to identify the longest elements on the left-hand side (LHS) and right-hand side (RHS) of either set, and use that to prop out the shorter of the two:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% Loads amsmath

\begin{document}

\[
  \phantom{P_{333}}
  \mathllap{P} = \mathrlap{
  \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
    P_{11} & P_{12} & P_{13} & P_{14} \\
    P_{21} & P_{22} & P_{23} & P_{24} \\
    P_{31} & P_{32} & P_{33} & P_{34}
  \end{array}\right]
  }\phantom{YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY}
\]
where 
\begin{align*}
  P_{11} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
  P_{12} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
  P_{13} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
  P_{14} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  P_{21} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
  P_{22} &= YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY \\% Longest RHS
  P_{23} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
  P_{24} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  P_{31} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
  P_{32} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
  P_{333} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\% Longest LHS
  P_{34} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

In the example above, `P_{333}` is the longest LHS member, and `YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY` is the longest RHS member. We use these to prop out the LHS `P` and RHS `<array>` via a `\phantom`. The original content is set using `\mathllap` and `\mathrlap` ([`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)) - a `l`eft/`r`ight over`lap` kept in `math` mode.

Alignment across the page break will not be visible usually to the end-user, so it's typically not needed. However, an easier alternative is to set `where` using

```
...
\shortintertext{where}
...
```

also provided by `mathtools` ([`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\intertext`) - see [Is it possible to break up an `align` environment and keep the tab positions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100867/5764). You may also want to set `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble, but that depends on your use of the `align`-like environments.

Answer (score 4):

You can use only one `align` environment that will break across pages with the `\allowdisplaybreaks` switch. Note that if you use `empheq` with option `overload`, you cannot break across pages anymore. To do so, you will have to use the `AmSalign` environment. I also replaced `array` with `bmatrix`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\mbox{}
\vskip10cm
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align*}
P & =
\begin{bmatrix}
P_{11} & P_{12} & P_{13} & P_{14} \\
P_{21} & P_{22} & P_{23} & P_{24} \\
P_{31} & P_{32} & P_{33} & P_{34} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\intertext{where}
P_{11} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{12} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{13} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{14} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
P_{21} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{22} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{23} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{24} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
P_{31} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{32} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{33} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
P_{34} &= XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]